# Ubuntu device battery update causing laptop to not charge

Tags: 22.04, battery, thinkpad

Have a thinkpad P15 running ubuntu 22.04. I recently selected an update provided in the ubuntu software for a battery update.

Now the battery won’t charge. On restart it now reads the “The connected AC adapter has a lower wattage than the recommended AC adapter which was shipped with its system. To use AC power please connect the adapter that was shipped with the system”. I am using the charger that came with the system.

Is there a way to undo this device battery update?

Edit:

The charger is working fine on the windows 10 OS (I dual boot for gaming and excel). This is now solely an ubuntu issue and the charger appears to be fine.

Comment: Was it a regular update received via update manager? Was it some sort of a firmware update in the software center?